# Table's join based on similarity and difference

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following tables

```
Table 1
ID  VAL ID2
1   a   x   
1   b   x   
1   b   z   
2   a   x   
3   a   y   

Table 2
ID  VAL ID2 
1   a   x   
1   b   y   
1   b   x   
1   b   k
```

I want to find rows from table 1 where ID and VAL are equal to Id and VAL of table 2, and table's 1 ID2 is not equal to ID2 from table 2.

The sql I try is

```
    SELECT
     t1.ID,t1.VAL,t1.ID2
     FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID 
     AND t1.Val=t2.Val AND t1.id2!=t2.ID2
    WHERE
    t2.ID IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY t1.ID,t1.VAL,t1.ID2 ;
```

and the results are

```
ID  VAL ID2
1   b   x
1   b   z
```

but the result I want is

```
ID  VAL ID2 
1   b   z
```

Please advice

Thank you

Comment: Change the join so that: `AND t1.id2!=t2.ID2` becomes `AND t1.id2<t2.ID2`  1.b.x and 1.b.z match on the first two columns so the self join is resulting in both rows being compared when you only want to consider the last one. I think.

Comment: @xQbert that won't work

Comment: you are correct it will not.

Answer (score 1):

Just translate your rules -- all items where ID and Val match except those that ID, Val and ID2 match

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID,t1.VAL,t1.ID2
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID AND t1.Val=t2.Val

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID,t1.VAL,t1.ID2
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID AND t1.Val=t2.Val AND t1.ID2=t2.ID2
```

You could also do it with left joins and additional logic, but I think the simple is always better unless you find a need to optimize.  Also, this simple version (which we can easily see logically correct) will let you validate more complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

I like Hogan's reasoning: simple can be best. However, it can be simplified further; plus Oracle's relational minus operator is `MINUS`:

```
  SELECT ID, VAL, ID2
    FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 USING ( ID, Val )
  MINUS
  SELECT ID, VAL, ID2
    FROM Table1 NATURAL JOIN Table2;
```

---

If you feel the need to code defensively against someone else adding further columns to these tables then feel free to make the columns explicit (personally I've never seen such a scenario in the wild) e.g.

```
 WITH T1 AS ( SELECT ID, VAL, ID2 FROM Table1 ),
      T2 AS ( SELECT ID, VAL, ID2 FROM Table2 )
SELECT ID, VAL, ID2
  FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 USING ( ID, Val )
MINUS
SELECT ID, VAL, ID2
  FROM Table1 NATURAL JOIN Table2;
```

Comment: +1 This is very cool -- I don't understand why the first one is `USING` and the second is natural join -- is that because the example tables have exactly 3 columns?

Comment: ah, yes I stated my point badly, try again:  I don't think it is a good idea to use a `NATURAL JOIN` because while it will often work for the question posted is may cause issues for a questioner when applied to production system.  In the same way it is bad to use `*` in the select list.

Comment: @Hogan: defensive programming is a balancing act :) See update to answer.

Comment: I like your new answer a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the your question correct and according to your result please, find the the same code.

```html
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE (ID INT, VAL VARCHAR(10), ID2 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Table1(Id,Val,ID2)
VALUES (1,'a','x'),
(1,'b','x')   ,
(1,'b','z') ,     
(2,'a','x')  ,    
(3,'a','y ')     

DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE (ID INT, VAL VARCHAR(10), ID2 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Table2(Id,Val,ID2)
VALUES (1,   'a', 'x'),   
(1,   'b',   'y'),   
(1,   'b',   'x'),   
(1,   'b',   'k')


--I want to find rows from table 1 where ID and VAL are equal to Id and VAL of table 2,--and table's 1 ID2 is not equal to ID2 from table 2.   
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.Id AND T2.VAL = t1.VAL
AND t2.ID2 != t1.ID2
EXCEPT 
SELECT *
FROM @Table2
```

Comment: This is the same as my answer with some errors added -- just 15 mins later -- why post the same as my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I interpert the rules correctly, you want all records from table1 not in table2 based on ID, val and ID2, except for those with no record in table2 at all.

```
with table1(ID, val, ID2) as
(Select 1, 'a','x' from dual UNION ALL
Select 1, 'b','x' from dual UNION ALL
Select 1, 'b','z' from dual UNION ALL
Select 2, 'a','x' from dual UNION ALL
Select 3, 'a','y' from dual),
table2(ID, val,ID2) as (
Select 1,   'a',  'x'     from dual UNION ALL
Select 1,   'b',   'y'   from dual UNION ALL
Select 1,   'b' ,  'x'   from dual UNION ALL
Select 1,   'b',   'k'  from dual)


   SELECT
     t1.ID,t1.VAL,t1.ID2
     FROM Table1 t1 
   LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
     ON t1.ID=t2.ID 
     AND t1.Val=t2.Val
     and t1.Id2=t2.ID2
    WHERE t2.ID2 IS NULL 
      and exists (Select t2a.ID 
                  from table2 t2a 
                  where t2a.id = t1.id
                  --and  t2a.val = t1.val; 
                 );
```

--but maybe you also need what's commented out but I don't follow the requirements well enough to know.

Comment: This won't work add the following to table1 - `1,'d','z'`

Comment: Returns 2 records as I would want it to.  `1,'d','z'` doesn't exist in table 2.  but 1 Does. since 1ax and 1bx exist in table2 they are excluded.  records 2,3 don't get included as no ID exists in table2 with those two values.  And since 1bz and 1dx don't exist in table 2 but ID 1 does, both records are returned.  If we want to match on ID and val, then the exists subquery would be modified to include an additional where `and t2a.val = t1.val`.

Comment: ok, but that is not the requirements -- requirements state that `1, 'd'` are in table2 in order to return my example record.